# RecyclerView icon is stateless and when go to other activity it return to default state

Tags: android

I have a one ImageView (With border heart icon) in each row of my

`recyclerview`. I use this icon for add to favorite list . when I press this

image view it's change to other icon (complete heart icon) . every thing is ok 
, But when i go to other

Activity it return to the default icon (border heart icon) . I use the flag for doing this work .

> This is my RecyclerView Adapter (image onClick event):

```
   //============== IMG ADD TO FAVORITE CLICK LISTENER ======================
        holder.imgAddFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            boolean flag = false;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                QuestionDatabaseAdapter databaseAdapter = new QuestionDatabaseAdapter(v.getContext());

                if (!flag) {

                    ModelQuestion question = new ModelQuestion();


                    question.setQuestionTitle(questionha.get(position).getQuestionTitle());
                    question.setQuestionDesc(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDesc());
                    question.setQuestionDate(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDate());
                    question.setQuestionAuthorName(questionha.get(position).getQuestionAuthorName());
                    question.setQuestionAuthorPic(questionha.get(position).getQuestionAuthorPic());
                    question.setQuestionDownLink(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDownLink());

                    databaseAdapter.saveQuestion(question);

                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Added !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    holder.imgAddFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_red_700_24dp);
                    flag = true;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Removed !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    holder.imgAddFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_red_a700_24dp);
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

And this is my icons .
[image]

Comment: use a database to store the states and then you can retrieve it and display proper icon

Comment: This RecyclerVeiw populate with json

Comment: You need to mechanism to store the state of the icon somewhere. How you do it is left to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain the state of your each item, in your model class create a boolean for ex:"isClicked", by default make it false, when he clicks make it true in adapter onclick, u need to display item based on this "isClicked" property.

```
if(isClicked){
//show filled heart

 }else{
 //show empty heart

}
```

Comment: are you mean database or QuestionModel ?

Comment: @g0labi did u try?

Comment: I add the private  boolean var (isClicked = false) . and set the getter and setter for that.

Comment: @g0labi yes exactly !!:)

Comment: but this isn't work , changing from false to true is work , but changing from true to false nothing work and although it isn't save the state of icon , when i change the icon and go to other activity , it isn't save the icon state

Comment: in your activity onResume call notifyDatasetChanged() ,keep the same code try this...it should work man..

Comment: i added to questionactivity but nothing

Comment: r u finishing the activity when u r navigating from one activity to other?

Comment: yes when i click home button in toolbar i finish the activity

Comment: could you post ur complete code in pastebin and give link?

Comment: from second activity to first activity finishing activity is fine, but from first activity to second activity if there is a finish then remove..

Comment: ok..The prob is in "question.setIsClicked(true);" don set for this object bec it is created each time, instead questionha.get(position).setIsClicked(true or false), replace with this.and change if(!questionha.isClicked())...check this

Comment: Thank you man , it change the icon great but icons are stateless still .

Comment: what you think about share prefrences ? is it good for this work ?

Comment: ok now ckeck putting adapterobject.notifydatasetChanged() in onResume() of ur activity...

Comment: the approach i told is applies when u scroll down or up it will keep ur states, but when you come back from other activity by default it should keep the states as same as when u left the first activity...but i don no wts goin on here...

Comment: could u post ur activity?

Comment: and where is ur startActivity();?

Comment: in The previouse activty adapter recyclerview.

Comment: no , in the previouse activity i populate other recyclerview . with clicking on the previouse recyclerview item , it send id of item to current recyclerview( in fact it send id to this recyclerview)

Comment: how many activities u have actually??? and when u click on this recyclerview item where it should go?? and u r asking to maintain this recyclerview item state right?

Comment: i have 5 activity (like a chain they are send id of previuse recycler id to other),my question is how can i know which item of recyclerview added to favorite list and which item not added ?

Comment: u can easily identify through that model class man, through that "isClicked" property, if it is true then it has added to favourite else not no...simple...

Comment: but to identiffy that u should pass that model class back wherever u want...there u should check..

Comment: should pass this list of madel class "questionha"

Comment: when u click on the item of this recyclerview the image will get changed to full heart right, then we will store that item state in "isClicked" property as true..This item will be in "questionha" arraylist...i need to know after he clicks on the recyclerview item where u r taking the control to? next activity? or previous activity?

Comment: this activity is the end of app tree , in each row of activity i have one button for downloading something , and after this activity doesn't anything

Comment: ok, where you want to check the state then? previous activity? after click onBackPressed in existing activity?

Comment: in the current activity (my mean is QuestionActivity) . please see this image http://s7.picofile.com/file/8252789784/Capture.JPG

Comment: could you tell me restoring the state means when you want to restore it? when he comes back second time to this activity? or while scrolling? u said image is getting changed right? m not getting on which scenario u r telling that state is not storing...for first time u come to this activity? or second time?

Comment: the thing is m not getting clear picture of ur scenario:( or else it will be solved by this time...

Comment: look my friend in the question activity (that picture i send from my app)i have recyclerview that populate with json . then as you see in the pic each item of recyclerview have a one img(heart) and one button . with clicking on the button it starting downlod something . and i want when user click on heart it save the json data to database(i solve this part before) and bordered heart chang to solid heart . it worked when i'm in the question activity , but when i go to previouse activity or exit the app . all of heart still borderd . this is my mean of state.

Comment: in previous activity how u will get to know that the state is not stored? in previous activity also u  have recycler with same items?

Answer (score 0):

It will return to default icon at `holder.imageView.setImageResource();` 
To over come this store the items added to favourite list and then set the image properly.

```
//this is a simple code to check whether its in favourite
//itemMap is a static HashMap<Integer,Boolean>
// make a statement like isFavorite=itemMap !=null && itemMap.get(new Integer(position) to be used in if else statement
//use the hashmap for current use. If hasgmap is null retrieve it from a database.
//you should probably do that at the constructor of the adapter
if(isInFavourites){
   holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.favouriteImage);
}else{
   holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.addFavImage);
}
```

Its always good practice to store the favourite item at onClick in a hash map and in a database using a new thread to prevent a possible lag.

**Explanation as requested**

- You have a `onBIndViewHolder()` method in your recycle view adapter and it contains the method `holder.imgAddFav.setImageResource()` which you use to add the *favourite border* image.
- The adapter calls that function whenever the recycle view items are created and the bordered image is set as a result.
- So at imgAddFav onClick you save the newly added item to favorites in a static hashMap that you've declared as an instance variable.

  ```
  //consider the hashMap as favMap;
  HashMap<Integer,Boolean> favMap;

  //at the constructor of the recylcer view you've to check whether you have items that you previously added to the favorite list
  public YourAdapter(/*parameters*/){
     if(favMap==null){
        favMap=new HashMap<>();
     }
     //now fill the map with stored data
     //You can use sharedpreferences or a datase
     //for an example think that postio 2 is in favorites;
     favMap.put(new Integer(2),true);
  }
  ```
- Now back to the `getItemHolder()`. Here before setting the imgAddFav image check from the hashmap whether the particular position is in favourites.

  ```
      //set a boolean to check whether this item is in favorites
      boolean isInFavorites;
      if(favMap.contains(new Integer(position)) && favMap.get(new Integer(position){
        //the item is in the favourite list
        //set the full colored image
        holder.imgAddFav.setImageResource(R.id.coloredHeart);
        isInFavorites=true;
     }else{
        holder.imgAddFav.setImageResource(R.id.borderedHeart);
        isInFavorites=false;
     }
  ```
- Now at onclick not only change the image but store the result as well

  ```
  holder.imgAddFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
       @Overrride
       public void onClick(View v){
          if(isInFavorites){
             favMap.put(new Integer(position),false);
             //save this same thing in a database or sharedPreference.Do it in a new thread.
             //if you want to save to a database
             new Thread(new Runnable{
                 @Override
                 public void run(){
                    //insert into database
                 }
             }).start();
            //or else if you want save to sharedPreference you can use edit.apply() method
            //now change the image or simply call notify datasetChanged
            notifyDatasetChanged();  
          }
       }
  });
  ```